# Unity - Moving Platform from Point A to Point B

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, platform

I am trying to make a game in Unity and I am stuck in a part where I am trying to move a platform from Point A to Point B.

The error I get is:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MovingPlatform.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/MovingPlatform.cs:30)

The Source Code is:

```cs
public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform pointA, pointB;

    private float speed = 1.0f;

    private Transform target;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position == pointA.position)
        {
            target = pointB;
        }
        else if (transform.position == pointB.position)
        {
            target = pointA;
        }
        
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

What should I do?

Because the platform is not moving at all.

Comment: I recommend you look into how debugging works. [Unity Manual Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html). The answer is correct too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you whats wrong. In line 30 of your script you have a reference somewhere which is `null` (hence `NullReferenceException`) and you try to do something with this (e.g. accessing attributes). I guess its `target.position` from

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

when your `if`-statements dont trigger. You should add `target = pointB;` in `Start()`
to have `target` properly initialized (i assume you want start out moving to `pointB`).